# The correct pronunciation of ᙯ (q) in Inuktitut?

Tags: pronunciation, inuktikut

According to Wikipedia and various internet source the consonant of ᙯ (written "q" in Latin script) is pronounced [q] (IPA notation), but when I hear it spoken in songs or videos (for example the word Qallunaat in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lazUV7PEw7w ) I hear it as [x] (a non-sibilant fricative) and not [q] (a plosive).
What is happening?